# How can I resolve '_ORMJoin' object has no attribute issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, sqlalchemy, orm

I've a python ORM query and I'm getting an error given below. It's telling me object has no attribute 'name'. Getting the error when I join this part : join(Fund, Fund.id == Order.fund_id). Can you please check what I can do to fix this issue?

```
query = db.session.query(APFirm, Order, Fund.client_id, Fund.clientagreement_id).outerjoin(Order, APFirm.id == Order.apfirm).join(Fund, Fund.id == Order.fund_id)
```

Error :

```
'_ORMJoin' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace and make sure that this is not a two part stack trace where the mentioned exception is actually following a previous exception?

Comment: It seems that sometimes this exception can occur if a foreign key, such as `Order.fund_id` is not resolvable.  Maybe a typo like `ForeignKey('Wunds.id')` instead of `ForeignKey('Funds.id')`.